# How to fetch HTML Input Id in code behind ASP.Net MVC ? Either on Controller or on Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to fetch HTML Input Id in code behind ASP.Net MVC ? Either on Controller or on Model ?

view / .cshtml

```
<button type="submit" id="previewButton" >Preview</button>
```

JQuery : - This will not be in use.

```
$("button").click(function ()
    {
        var btn = this.id;
          alert(btn);
   }
```

In Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(MyViewModel viewModel, string clickedButton)
        {

            var vm = clickedButton;
            return View(vm);
        }
```

- MyViewModel

  public string clickedButton { get; set; }

Comment: A form posts back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls (not its `id` attribute). Make the button `<button type="submit" name="clickedButton" value="xxxx">Preview</button>`, and if you click that button, the value of your parameter will be "xxxx"

Comment: But if you have a property for it in the model, then you do not need the `string clickedButton` parameter (the value of the property will be bound with the value of the button).

Comment: @StephenMuecke , In this syntax .. <button type="submit" id="previewButton" >  - You want me to replace Id with name ? Is that right? Doing so will suffice the problem ?

Comment: Exactly as per my first comment - you need a `name` attribute which must match the name of the parameter (or model property), and a `value` attribute (and the parameter or property will be bound with that value)

Comment: i am not able to retrieve the name (or) id

Comment: Then I can only assume you did not click on that button